# currentUser is displayed undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When i signup, I am redirected to /dashboard page which has Navbar component. It is linked with ReactMeteorData that is defined in ReactMeteorDataWrap.jsx. After signing up, i get Object {_id: "qW8wQcc2sjiM8TXcc", profile: Object, emails: Array[1]} data Object {currentUser: Object} on console. However currentUser is displayed null.

**my code**

**ReactMeteorDataWrap.jsx**

```
const ReactMeteorDataWrap = (BaseComponent)=>{
    return class ExportClass extends Component { 
        getMeteorData(){
            let data = {};
            console.log(Meteor.user());
            data.currentUser = Meteor.user();
            console.log('data',data);
            return data;
        }
        render(){
            return <BaseComponent getMeteor={()=>this.getMeteorData()} 
                 {...this.props}></BaseComponent>
        }
    }
}

export default ReactMeteorDataWrap;
```

**Navbar.jsx(/dashboard)**

```
 import ReactMeteorDataWrap from '../ReactMeteorDataWrap.jsx';

    class Navbar extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { searchText: '' };
            this.props.getMeteor(); //accessed from ReactMeteorDataWrap 
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            const users = Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{'profile':1}}).fetch();
            const usernames = [];
            users.map(function(user){
                usernames.push(user.profile.fullname);
            });
            $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'users',
                local: usernames
            });
        }

        handleSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            FlowRouter.go('/user/' + (this.refs.searchText.value).trim());
        }

        render() {
             let fullname = '';
             let currentUser = this.props.currentUser;
             console.log('currentUser',this.props.currentUser); // returns undefined 
            if(currentUser && currentUser.profile){
                console.log('currentUser',currentUser);
                fullname =  currentUser.profile.firstname + ' ' + currentUser.profile.lastname;
            }
            console.log('fullname',fullname); // returns null
            return (
                        <div className="navbar navbar-blue navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div className="navbar-header">
                                <a href="/dashboard" className="navbar-brand logo"><i className="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <nav className="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-home"></i> News Feed</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li className="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> {fullname}</a>
                                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="/profile">Edit Profile</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/signout">Logout</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default ReactMeteorDataWrap(Navbar);
```

**SignupForm.jsx(after signing up user will be redirected to dashboard page which has navbar above)**

```
import ReactMeteorDataWrap from '../ReactMeteorDataWrap.jsx';

class SignupForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            messageClass:''
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.props.getMeteor();
    }

    displayError(message){
        console.log(message);
        this.setState({
            message:message,
            messageClass:'alert alert-danger registerError'
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({message:'', messageClass:'hidden'});
        const first_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.first_name).value.trim();
        const last_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.last_name).value.trim();
        const email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value.trim();
        const password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value.trim();
        const user = {
            email:email,password:password,
            profile:{
                fullname:(first_name + last_name).toLowerCase(), 
                firstname:first_name, lastname:last_name,
                avatar:'http://placehold.it/150*150',
                friends:[]
            }
        }
        Accounts.createUser(user,(e) => {
            console.log('user',user);
            console.log('e',e);
            if (e) {
                this.displayError(e.reason);
            } else {
                FlowRouter.go('/dashboard');
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="signup">
                    <h1>Sign up</h1>
                    <p className="text-muted">It's free and will always be</p>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" ref="first_name" className="form-control"/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" ref="last_name" className="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email or mobile number" ref="email" className="form-control"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ref="password" className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-md btn-success">signup</button>
                        <span className={this.state.messageClass}>{this.state.message}</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ReactMeteorDataWrap(SignupForm);
```

Is calling getMeteorData() through props in both SignupForm and Navbar.jsx ok? Because i wanted to use mixins functionality in es6 way.

Comment: instead of this.props.currentUser you do this.props.getMeteor().currentUser, it will work.

Comment: I would take a look at [react-komposer](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-komposer) for a reactive higher order component composition implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When you log in and you're redirected to /dashboard, two things happen at once:

1. React renders the new components
2. Meteor starts to synchronize the `Meteor.users` collection.

There's no guarantee that `Meteor.user()` is available by the time React starts rendering. In fact it's very probable that the user is still undefined when the React component mounts.

When your `ReactMeteorDataWrap.render` calls `getMeteorData`, the user still is undefined, that's what you see. The problem is that your code doesn't call `getMeteorData` again when the user document is updated.

There are several ways you can fix this. I'd recommend using `createContainer` form the [react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) package, which is similar to your `ReactMeteorDataWrap` class, except that it actually works. :)

Here's a fix that makes `this.props.user` be available in `NavBar`:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  return { user: Meteor.user() };
}, NavBar);
```

Comment: yes you are right when i sign up and i am redirect to dashboard page then the username is displayed but if i refresh the dashboard page i get username as undefined.

Comment: I am having problem with these mixins. My dashboard page wants just the username so there is ReactMeteorDataWrap and i need to use this ReactMeteorDataWrap for statusForm too but instead of only username i need to fetch all the post of that user.